# static fields in a shared assembly

Tags: c#, gac

If a shared assembly (in the GAC) has a static field, and the value of the field is updated, will that be reflected in the client application which is referencing the shared assembly?
Or does the client application will need a rebuild?

Answer (score 6):

If the field is expressed as a `const`:

```
public const int Foo = 100;
```

then you'll need to rebuild all client apps, as the value will be baked into those clients.

If it's just a public static readonly field:

```
public static readonly int Foo = 100;
```

... then you won't need to rebuild the client. The value will be fetched from the assembly at execution time. (Of course, the client would need to be executing *using* the new assembly, so you need to consider versioning etc.)

Comment: Best answer! (Y)

Answer (score 5):

In .NET statics are per [AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173138%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), so even if the assembly is in the `GAC`, the scope of any static variable declared in it exists just in the referencing AppDomain.
If you are talking as a static initialized to a literal ( independetly that is readonly or not) it will be automatically reflected in all assemblies using it without recompiling them.

Answer (score 0):

If the field is not marked as a constant then it shouldn't require a recompile of the client as each time the field is accessed the value will be returned.

If it is marked as a constant then the client will require a recompile as the value of the field is "baked" at compilation.